# Problem based on Permutation - combination

Tags: permutations, combinations

Here's a permutation combination sum that I often bump into, but cannot solve it, may be due to some misconceptions. 
Let's take an example.
There are 4 letters and 4 addressed envelopes. Find the probability that any one will go to the correct envelope. 
It came to my mind that,
Total number of ways is $\mathrm 4!$.
Now, number of ways by which this can be done is 4C1×1×(number of ways by which the letters go into wrong envelope). I hope this far I have gone right.
But how to find the number of ways by which the letters go in wrong envelopes? I'm struck in there, and I believe someone needs to give me a clear explanation in order to make this thing clear in my mind. 
Thanks

Comment: Look up on the web on derrangements, inclusion-exclusion principle

Comment: Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) is quite good. For the case of $4$, you could do it by making a careful list. Call the letters A, B, C, D. If no letter ends up in the right envelope, then letter A ends up in the envelope for B, C, or D. Count the cases in which it ends up in the envelope for B, and multiply by $3$. You will find there are $3$ permutations in which the letter A ends up in the envelope for B and no letter ends up in the right envelope, so total $9$. For larger numbers, like $7$ letters, we begin to need some theory.

Comment: Are you asking for the probability that exactly one letter will be placed in the correct envelope?